# How do I get each instance to inherit their own instance of a member?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In the following code, I have two Book Collections. One collection has "Moby Dick," while the other collection has "The Firm." However, when I look at the second collection, it also has Moby Dick. How do I create Books that do not share the same data?

```
function Collection () {
    var stuff = [];
    this.get = function () {
        return stuff;
    };
    this.add = function (item) {
        stuff.push(item);
    };
}
function Books () {}
Books.prototype = new Collection ();

var myBooks = new Books();
myBooks.add("Moby Dick");

var yourBooks = new Books();
yourBooks.add("The Firm");

console.log(yourBooks.get()); // ["Moby Dick", "The Firm"]
```

I ended up going with this:

```
function Collection () {
    var stuff = [];
    this.get = function(){
        return stuff;
    };
    this.add = function(item){
        stuff.push(item);
    };
}
function Books () {
    Collection.call(this);
};

Books.prototype = new Collection();

Books.prototype.constructor = Books;

var myBooks = new Books();
myBooks.add("Moby Dick");

var yourBooks = new Books();
yourBooks.add("The Firm");

console.log(myBooks.get());
```

Comment: You make the Books prototype *itself* an *instance* of Collection, which I don't think is what you want. See Matt's answer below, you want `stuff` to be a Collection, and a property of Books.

Answer (score 5):

Use a per-instance value with `this`:

```
function Books () {
    this.stuff = [];
}
```

And then in the collection:

```
this.get = function () {
    return this.stuff;
};
```

Currently only one `stuff` array is created when you set the prototype of Books. All the inherited getters and setters then refer to that one variable.

---

[Complete code](http://jsbin.com/ARuZIJo/1/edit):

```
function Collection () {
    this.get = function () {
        return this.stuff;
    };
    this.add = function (item) {
        this.stuff.push(item);
    };
}
function Books () {
    this.stuff = [];
}

Books.prototype = new Collection ();

var myBooks = new Books();
myBooks.add("Moby Dick");

var yourBooks = new Books();
yourBooks.add("The Firm");

console.log(myBooks.get()); // ["Moby Dick"]
console.log(yourBooks.get()); // ["The Firm"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep "stuff" private?

Comment: You can by using var stuff = []; However stuff will only be available inside Collection if you resource to do so. Check my answer bellow, I also posted a link to an article that can help you understand OOP in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of structural issues with your code. Your methods in Collection should also be prototyped and they currently are not. If you dont prototype the methods trying to get access to "stuff" you endup with multiple functions referencing the exact same property instead of creating their own instance of that property. Follow this structure instead:

Main **Collection** Class

```
function Collection () {
    this.stuff = [];
};

Collection.prototype.get = function(){
    return this.stuff;
};

Collection.prototype.add = function(item){
    this.stuff.push(item);
}
```

Main **Books** Class Inherits From **Collection**

```
function Books () {
    Collection.call(this);
};

Books.prototype = new Collection();
Books.prototype.constructor = Books;
```

Using Your **Books** Class

```
var myBooks = new Books();
myBooks.add("Moby Dick");

var yourBooks = new Books();
yourBooks.add("The Firm");

console.log(yourBooks.get());
```

JSFiddle with working example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlitos/UDvyV/1/)

Source where you can get further details regarding Javascript prototype:

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Let me know bellow if you have any questions about the code itself or this change in structure.